# Impresión de arreglos

Tags: array

Tengo éste codigo, donde al mandar a imprimir debería de aparecer un arreglo, pero no se imprime, ¿Qué me está fallando? ¿Qué debería hacer para que se vea el arreglo?
De antemano gracias

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr1[4][5][2], var,i,j,k;
int *point;
void main(){
int i;
point = arr1;
var=5;
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
    for (j=0;j<5;j++){
        for (k=0;k<2;k++){
            arr1[i][j][k]=var;
            var+=5;
        }
    }
}
int a= *(point+3);
printf("%d\n", a);
int b= *(point+12);
printf("%d", b);
int c= *(point+27);
int d= *(point+37);
```

}

Comment: Buenas, Neo, bienvenido al sitio. No soy experto en C, pero no se ve en tu código ningún sitio donde se imprima el arreglo. Los printf solo imprimen un número. Al igual que empleas bucles for para inicializarlo, ¿no deberías emplearlos tambien para imprimir cada una de sus posiciones? Por otro lado, si te fijas la palabra reservada var te la está coloreando de forma especial. No llames var a una variable, ponle un nombre identificativo. En tu caso podría ser algo así como contador o acumulador o algo relacionado con lo que aparezca descrito en el enunciado del ejercicio

Answer (score 1):

Como comenta @RubioRic en un comentario, debes emplear la función `printf` cuando quieras imprimir un número, carácter o lo que quieras.
Siguiendo el consejo del comentario, C sólo puede imprimir variable a variable, por lo que debes tener un bucle `for` que vaya recorriendo todas las posiciones del array tridimensional que has creado.

Podría ser algo así:

```
printf("IMPRIMIENDO ARRAY...\n");
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
    for (j=0;j<5;j++){
        for (k=0;k<2;k++){
            printf("%d ", arr1[i][j][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora, con esto, ya puedes empezar a jugar en cómo mostrar los datos, si quieres dejar un espacio después de cada número, un salto de línea cada vez que cambies de dimensión... Lo que quieras.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda ☺